# Magento2 add breadcrumb dynamically on custom pages

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

Magento2 How can I add breadcrumb dynamically on custom pages?

```
Home > FAQ > Carpet FAQ
Home > FAQ > Shutters FAQ
```

Where Carpet & Shutters are dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve by using the below code in the block file.

```
  public function _prepareLayout()
        {
            $breadcrumbsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
            $baseUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    
            if ($breadcrumbsBlock) {
    
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                    'home',
                    [
                    'label' => __('FAQ'), //lable on breadCrumbes
                    'title' => __('Carpet FAQ'),
                    'link' => $baseUrl
                    ]
                );
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                    'coderkube',
                    [
                    'label' => __('Carpet FAQ'),
                    'title' => __('Carpet FAQ'),
                    'link' => '' //set link path
                    ]
                );
            }
            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('FAQ')); // set page name
            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom controller you can add breadcrumbs using below code.

> resultPageFactory is Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory

```
public function execute(){  
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $breadcrumbsBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
    if ($breadcrumbsBlock) {
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'home',
            [
                'label'    => __('Home'),
                'link'     => $this->_url->getUrl('')
            ]
        );
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'faq',
            [
                'label'    => __('Faq'),
                'link'     => $this->_url->getUrl('faq')
            ]
        );
        /* you can add here your confition for dynamic element*/
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
            'carpet_faq',
            [
                'label'    => __('Carpet FAQ'),
                'link'     => $this->_url->getUrl('carpetfaq')
            ]
        );
    }
    return $resultPage;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add via controller but not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add breadcrumb through Plugins, you cannot use the method _prepareLayout because it is protected.
You can use setLayout method instead with after method :

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugins\Block;

class AddCustomBreadcrumb
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function afterSetLayout($subject, $result)
    {
        $breadcrumbsBlock = $subject->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
    
        if ($breadcrumbsBlock) {

            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                'home',
                [
                    'label' => __('Home'), //lable on breadCrumbes
                    'title' => __('Back Home'),
                    'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(),
                ]
            );
            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                'storelocator',
                [
                    'label' => __('Carpet FAQ'),
                    'title' => __('Carpet FAQ'),
                    'link' => '' //set link path
                ]
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now you need to declare your plugin in di.xml :
Edit/Add the file app/code/VENDOR/EXTENSION/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

  <type name="Vendor\Module\Block\BlockName">
    <plugin name="YourVendor_Module::add_custom_breadcrumb" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugins\Block\AddCustomBreadcrumb" sortOrder="999"/>
  </type>
</config>
```